# Qt5: default stylesheet of a PushButton for a Label

Tags: css, qt5, pyqt5

I am working on a PyQt5 project and would like my labels' background color to disappear with time such as the blue background color of QPushButtons when you pass the mouse over it.

The idea is that each time the text of the label is updated, its background color change and resorb on a few seconds just like pushButtons when you pass the mouse over them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `QTimer` to reset the stylesheet back after a set amount of time.

```
button.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {background: red;}')
QTimer.singleShot(2000, lambda: button.setStyleSheet(''))
```

If you wanted more complex transitions (like a gradual fading out of color), you probably want to use the [Qt animation framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/animation-overview.html).